# How to get FileName without Extension from Local File URL in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I have an array of URLs(Local Files).How can I get the filename without the extension.

So far I know how to get the filename with the extension.Is there an inbuilt function to do this.Something similar to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var file_name = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path_to_file).lastPathComponent!
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the `URL` class?

Comment: @rmaddy The Answer to the linked question shows how to split the file path from the extension.I want to get the file name only. My question is-is there any inbuilt parameters or function to get the file name.This ideally should be achieved with a simple single line of code as in C#.It seems I need to do custom string manipulation.

Comment: @rmaddy I Have gone through the documentation over here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url .Its not helpful at all.There are few Topics related to Local Files.Thus this question.

Comment: The linked question has many answers, not just one. Did you see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41386089/1226963)?

Comment: How is the documentation not helpful? It clearly show a method for removing the extension. And your question isn't specific to local files. It applies to any URL.

Comment: @rmaddy Its clear from the title `how-to-get-filename-without-extension-from-local-file-url-in-swift` ,that the question applies to local files.

Comment: You missed my point. Any answer applies equally well to both local and remote URLs. Look at the specific answer I linked. It is exactly what you want.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes,but I have to go through every answer to find it out.So the question is not the exact duplicate.That's my point.

Comment: @techno Dude, what's unhelpful? Just do a local search through the documentation page for `URL` for "extension" and before too long, you'll find a method called `.deletingPathExtension()`. Gee, I wonder what that does?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Thing is why don't they put up any sample code ? or just a clean single function to do the job like in C#.You need to remove the extension and get the last path component :).I think SWIFT Documentation and the language itself needs to be improved further.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka See how a helpful documentation looks like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @techno You mean like [this?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780065-deletingpathextension)

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Where is the sample code or any clear explanation?  Is the documentation intended only for experts?

Comment: @techno What's unclear about "Returns a URL constructed by removing any path extension."?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka There are no examples for almost everything.Frankly-The Documentation SUCKS!

Comment: `let filename = URL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePath).deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent`

Comment: @nicksweet Thanks... I already got the answer :)