# Getting a value from url by using components separated by string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a url that looks like this :

> https://google.com/image/ghwUT23Y.jpeg

I want to be able to achieve something like this:

```
section = image; 
value = ghwUT23Y;
```

I have tried to explode the url and use`componentsSeperatedByString`method to grab the values I need.

```
 if ([[explodedUrl firstObject] containsString:@"google.com"] && ![[explodedUrl firstObject] isEqualToString:@"https://google.com/"]) {

    NSString *sectionString = [[[explodedUrl lastObject] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] firstObject];
    NSLog(@"redirectttttt: %@",sectionString);
    NSString *itemString = [[[explodedUrl lastObject] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
    NSLog(@"redirectttttt:2 %@",itemString);
```

**Problem:**

Using this method, `itemString` returns me the value : `ghwUT23Y.jpeg`but `sectionString` returns me `https://`

How would I be able to get `image` as a section?

Comment: I would use `NSURLComponents` to get the components of an url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split filename from file extension in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707352/how-to-split-filename-from-file-extension-in-swift)

Comment: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com/image/ghwUT23Y.jpeg"]; NSArray *components = [url pathComponents]; NSString *imageSection = [components objectAtIndex:1]; NSString *imageName = [[components lastObject] stringByDeletingPathExtension];` should do the trick. I used direct index, but should be modified as needed.

Comment: Check this: `NSString * url = @"https://google.com/image/ghwUT23Y.jpeg";
    if ([url rangeOfString:@"image"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSArray *components = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        
        NSString * section = components[components.count - 2];
        NSString * value = [components lastObject];
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",section, value);
    }`

Comment: @Larme worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your string to url first and use the [pathComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1407365-pathcomponents) method to access each components of that url.

#### Objective C:

```
NSURL *url                 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ttps://google.com/image/ghwUT23Y.jpeg"];
NSMutableArray *components = [[url pathComponents] mutableCopy];
NSString *fileName         = [components lastObject];
[components removeLastObject];
NSString *section          = [components lastObject];
NSLog(@"File : %@, Section: %@",fileName, section);
```

#### Swift

```
let url        = URL(string: "https://google.com/image/ghwUT23Y.jpeg")
var components = url?.pathComponents
let fileName   = components?.popLast()
let section    = components?.popLast()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift :**

```
func detectUrl()  {
    let strLongDescription = "https://google.com/image/ghwUT23Y.jpeg"

    if(strLongDescription.contains("image")){

        var arrString : [String] = strLongDescription.components(separatedBy: "google.com/")
        let lastOfarrString : String = arrString.last!
        arrString = lastOfarrString.components(separatedBy: "/")
        let section = arrString.first!
        let value = arrString.last! 
    }
}
```